# How do I check that a subset is included in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have the following list of lists:

```
l =
[
 ['s1', 's5', 's6', 's8', 's10', 's5', 's15', 's23'],
 ['s1', 's5', 's8', 's10', 's5', 's6', 's8', 's15', 's23'],
 ['s1', 's5', 's6', 's10', 's14', 's15', 's23']
]
```

I want to drop all lists that do not fit the following constraint: the list must include `['s5','s6','s8']` and `['s15', 's23']`:

```
l1 = ['s5','s6','s8']
l2 = ['s15', 's23']
```

The expected result is:

```
[
 ['s1', 's5', 's6', 's8', 's10', 's5', 's15', 's23'],
 ['s1', 's5', 's8', 's10', 's5', 's6', 's8', 's15', 's23']
]
```

How can I do so?

I tried to use `set(l1).issubset(t)` and `set(l2).issubset(l)`, but `set` returns only unique values.

Comment: To clarify, the sublist matches need to be contiguous and order matters here? Will there be any overlap between the two target lists? If so, how should that be handled? Also, will it always be two target sublists, or should this generalize to N target sublists? Are `"s1"`, `"s2"` etc precisely/literally the data, or are those placeholders for arbitrary strings? Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen: Yes, the order matters in sublists, and they should be continuous. There is no overlap between target sublists. Finally, there might be many target sublists. I used 2 just as an example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` and `set` to check the condition.

Using `filter` you can maintain the order as well

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x : not(set(l1+l2)-set(x)), l))
>>> [['s1', 's5', 's6', 's8', 's10', 's5', 's15', 's23'], 
     ['s1', 's5', 's8', 's10', 's5', 's6', 's8', 's15', 's23']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do a membership check:

```
l = [
 ['s1', 's5', 's6', 's8', 's10', 's5', 's15', 's23'],
 ['s1', 's5', 's8', 's10', 's5', 's6', 's8', 's15', 's23'],
 ['s1', 's5', 's6', 's10', 's14', 's15', 's23']
]
l1 = ['s5','s6','s8']
l2 = ['s15', 's23']

l1_s = ''.join(l1)
l2_s = ''.join(l2)

print([x for x in l if l1_s in ''.join(x) and l2_s in ''.join(x)])

# [['s1', 's5', 's6', 's8', 's10', 's5', 's15', 's23'],
#  ['s1', 's5', 's8', 's10', 's5', 's6', 's8', 's15', 's23']]
```